# ЧПУ на symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony, маршрутизация, чпу

Есть проект на Symfony 1.4 и потребовалось сделать сразу несколько изменений:

1. ЧПУ-ссылки (сейчас они выглядят так: as-gard.ru/production/1/ - для
   категории и as-gard.ru/production/1/view/45/ - для товара)
2. Возможность редактировать категорию, чтобы на ней отображался текст,
   а не выводился первый товар из категории

В симфони и PHP, мягко говоря, новичок.

Это фрагмент из **routing.yml:**

```
production:
  url:   /production/:id_category/
  param: { id_category: \d+, module: production, action: list }
  
production_view:
  url:   /production/:id_category/view/:id/
  param: { id_category: \d+, id: \d+, module: production, action: list }
```

Это фрагмент **/apps/frontend/modules/production/actions/actions.class.php**

```
public function executeList(sfWebRequest $request)
     {
    
        if ($request->getParameter('id_category')){
    
            $this->id_root_cat  =   $request->getParameter('id_category');
            
        }
        
        $q  =   Doctrine_Query::create()->from('Product');

        // либо конкретный продукт
        if ($request->getParameter('id')) {
            $this->item         =   $q->where( 'id =?', $request->getParameter('id') )
                                                                    ->fetchOne();
        // Либо первый из первой подкатегории
        }
        else{   
            // получаем подкатегории
            $subMenu    =   Doctrine_Query::create()->from('Category')
                                                        ->where('category_id =?', $this->id_root_cat )
                                                            ->orderBy('category_id asc')
                                                                ->addOrderBy('lft asc')
                                                                    ->execute()
                                                                        ->getFirst();
                                                                        
            if ($subMenu->getNode()->hasChildren()) {
                // если есть подкатегории - первый продукт из первой
                $id_cat =   $subMenu->getNode()->getFirstChild()->getId();
            } else {
                // иначе первый продукт
                $id_cat =   $this->id_root_cat;
            }
            
            $this->item         =   $q->where('id_category =?', $id_cat)
                                        ->orderBy('id asc')
                                            ->fetchOne();

        }
```

Пробовал в routing.yml прописывать что-то вроде

```
<pre>
production:
  url:   /production/:id_category/:cat_name/
  param: { cat_name, id_category: \d+, module: production, action: list }
</pre>
```

в action.class.php:

```
<pre>
if ($request->getParameter('cat_name')){
    
            $this->cat_name =   $request->getParameter('cat_name');
            
        }
</pre>
```

Предварительно создав в таблице столбец cat_name, записав это в schema.yml и обновив. Не понимаю, как это сделать